# Restrictions on new dependent variable

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

[image]

So if we have a new dependent variable $Y_i=\left(\mathrm{IncGrowth}  _i-\mathrm{PopGrowth} _i\right)$ and the new set of regressors is a constant term plus $\left(\mathrm{LogInc}_i-\mathrm{LogPop} _i\right)$ and $\left(\mathrm{LogEduc} _i-\mathrm{LogPop}_i\right)$. In terms of the original regression coefficients $\beta_1$ through $\beta_5$, how many restrictions does this regression impose and what are they?

I've been stuck at this problem for hours, can someone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original regression was:
$$y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_3 + b_4 x_4 + \epsilon$$

Your new regression is
\begin{align*}
y - x_4 &= c_0 + c_1( x_1 - x_3) + c_2 ( x_2 - x_3) + u \\
&y = c_0 + c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + (-c_1 - c_2) x_3 + x_4 + u
\end{align*}

The second regression is equivalent to the first where $b_4=1$ and $b_3 = - b_1 - b_2$.